# Ember's Router for pre4

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I'm trying to work with Ember's pre4 release, but I'm getting stuck on the Router.

I get an error that says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot Call method 'map' of undefined`.

Relavent code:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("about", { path: "/about" });
  this.route("favorites", { path: "/favs" });
});
```

Relative [documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/).

I've loaded Ember.js and jQuery. Ember pre4 also throws an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null`.

Am I doing something wrong? Are the guides just not updated?

---

The code I have so far:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
  ApplicationView: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application'
  }),
  ApplicationController: Ember.Controller.extend({
  }),

  SiteView: Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'site-template'
  }),
  SiteController: Em.ArrayController.extend(),

});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("about", { path: "/about" });
  this.route("favorites", { path: "/favs" });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing anything wrong with the code you posted. Was able to run it in jsbin, and after adding "site" as the default route the app appears to be working.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  ApplicationView: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application'
  }),
  ApplicationController: Ember.Controller.extend({
  }),

  SiteView: Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'site-template'
  }),
  SiteController: Em.ArrayController.extend()

});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("site", { path: "/" });
  this.route("about", { path: "/about" });
  this.route("favorites", { path: "/favs" });
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="site-template">
  This is the site template
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  This is the application template
  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

See [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwafej/3/edit) for working copy.

My best guess is that your errors are coming from some either an incompatible version of jQuery or because you don't have handlebars.js - both are required to run ember. Also, in development be sure to use [ember-1.0.0-pre.4.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/release-builds/ember-1.0.0-pre.4.js)! instead of ember-1.0.0-pre.4.min.js. The minimized version is optimized for production use so does not include helpful debug messages that will make it easier to spot these kind of problems.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing `handlebar.js` and needed to use the non-minified version. Thank you for pointing that out to me.